# SSIS Integration With GCP

Tags: ssis, google-cloud-platform

We are trying to upload file to GCP console, but the performance is impacting our data transfer , being a cloud hosted its taking much longer to upload as compared to a Azure or AWS services. Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you please provide more details? (How are you trying to upload the file? Which of the GCP products are you using? Etc.)

Comment: The console is a web portal which allows users to interact with GCP services. Of course, you can upload files using the console but this cannot be the case in an "un-attended" mode? Moreover, there is no SSIS runtime provided on GCP the only option you have is to host SSIS elsewhere or use IaaS to host SSIS on GCP.

Comment: We have already uploaded some files of around 2 GB in inside the bucket of GCP console , using SSIS script task . but the performance is slow around 35 minutes. Is there a code modification way to make it faster . We are using C# code inside SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons why you are experiencing slow uploads. You must verify and troubleshoot on the following lines:

- Is this purely related a case fo network bandwidth/congestion? Try upgrading your network bandwidth. If your case is more enterprise in nature, have you explored about `Dedicated Interconnect`
- Try disabling, versioning/encryption and other miscellaneous object-store features before the upload - they influence upload speed
- Are you copying data to the closest region where your bucket is launched? try changing your bucket relocation if this is not the case
- Have you considered a `multi-file upload or compressed file` upload strategy? This is result in faster upload speeds also.